# why COUNT function gives wrong input inside php and right result inside phpmyadmin sql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to count the rows which are not NULL inside a table when exucting the query inside Phpmyadmin it gives me the right output.

```
SELECT COUNT(`column_name`) FROM `Table_name`
```

but when I'm trying to execute it inside Php it always returns one I tried 2 methods both returning one for some reasons any ideas ?

method 1

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`column_name`) FROM `Table_name`";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        $field1name = $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);


        echo '<tr> 
                  <td>English</td> 
                  <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 

              </tr>';

    $result->free();
}
```

method 2

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`column_name`) FROM `Table_name`";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($rowcount = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);


        echo '<tr> 
                  <td>Bahdini</td> 
                  <td>'.$field1name.'</td> 

              </tr>';
    }
    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: You seem not to understand what your query returns

Comment: it should return number of rows that are nut null

Comment: No. You get the number of rows which contains the number of records which are not null.

Comment: So how many **data rows** this query returns when ie. 100 rows matches? And how many when 1?

Comment: in phpmyadmin it returns 10228 as a number of rows that are not null but in my php code it retuns 1

Comment: @Akina then how to return the number of the record I created instead of the rows any ideas ?

Comment: *in phpmyadmin it returns 10228 as a number of rows that are not null but in my php code it retuns 1* No. In phpadmin it returns **one row** which contains the value 10228. Your code returns 1 because it is one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several assigment in a row .. which is your expected  result ??

```
$field1name = $rowcount =mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Instaed  You should use a proper column alias for your count  and then  query, fecth, loop over the result and show

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(`column_name`) my_count FROM `Table_name`";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query );

     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "Name: " . $row["my_count"]. "<br>";
        }
     } else {
        echo "0 results";
     }
```

Comment: how to place the result into my table as my code above ? because when i try it it gives me error

Answer (score 2):

The SELECT COUNT Query returns a resultset of 1 row, in that row you get the number of rows: 10228 as you stated.

the function mysqli_num_rows returns the number of rows in the RESULTSET, that's why it returns 1.

Comment: then how to return the count query instead of the total number of rows which becomes 1